# Custom sidebar Link ist Gray

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, swiftui, sidebar

My SwiftUI app (for **iPad**) has a custom sidebar. But the options in the sidebar are gray - I think, all options are disabled. ChatGPT returns me just some else and not the bug. The same NavigationLink in right in a default sidebar, but it doesn't work in custom sidebar.
I want a button on all Views, which opens the sidebar. The default sidebar button on iPad is not "configurable".

Here is a screenshot and my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thapp.jpg)

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView : View {
@State private var sidebarShown = false
@State private var isOpen = false

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        if sidebarShown {
            CustomSidebar(sidebarShown: $sidebarShown, isOpen: $isOpen)
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                .transition(sidebarShown ? .move(edge: .leading) : .move(edge: .trailing) )
                
        }
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            MainContentView()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            if !sidebarShown {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        sidebarShown.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "sidebar.squares.left")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        .background(Color.black)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(50)
                    

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CustomSidebar.swift

```
struct CustomSidebar : View {
@Binding var sidebarShown : Bool
@Binding var isOpen: Bool

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                sidebarShown.toggle()
            }
        }) {
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "xmark.square.fill")
                Text("Close")
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    .imageScale(.large)
            }
            .padding(50)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: NewFormView()) {
                Label("Create new Form", systemImage: "doc.badge.plus")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: MyFormsView()) { // Angenommen, dass es eine MySolutionsView gibt
                Label("My Solutions", systemImage: "doc")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: FormTrackinView()) { // Angenommen, dass es eine LocationsView gibt
                Label("Locations", systemImage: "mappin.circle")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView()) {
                Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: AboutMeView()) { // Angenommen, dass es eine ProfileView gibt
                Label("Profile", systemImage: "person.circle")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: AboutMeView()) { // Angenommen, dass es eine AboutMeView gibt
                Label("About me", systemImage: "medal.fill")
            }

            // Weitere NavigationLinks hier...
            Spacer(minLength: 600)
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Text("Log out")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
       
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .frame(minWidth: 200, idealWidth: 250, maxWidth: 300)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                Button(action: {
                    isOpen.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                }
                .buttonStyle(SideMenuButtonStyle(isSideMenuOpen: isOpen))
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            Group {
                if isOpen {
                    Color.black.opacity(0.4)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isOpen.toggle()
                        }
                }
            }
        )
    }
    .background(Color.red)
}
```

Comment: You need a `NavigationStack`/`NavigationView`